# Alert variable defined in body from head

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have this simple HTML page which utilises Facebook Javascript SDK:

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script>
 alert(publish);
 </script>
 </head>

 <body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
       appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
       xfbml      : true,
       version    : 'v2.1'
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    });

    FB.api(
       "/me/permissions",
       function (response) {
          if(response && !response.error) {
              publish = '1';
          }
          else {
              publish = '0';
          }
       }
    );

 };
 (function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')); 
 </body>
</html>
```

I want to use the variable called `publish` which was defined inside the `FB.api` function. I want to use it from the  section but because it's defined later, it logs an undefined variable error. Is there a way around this?

Comment: i'm alerting in the head section in the demo above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here, a declaration problem and a timing problem.

As of your `alert` line, no variable called `publish` has been created. If you try to *read* the value of an undeclared symbol, it causes a `ReferenceError`. (If you try to *write* to an undeclared symbol, in loose mode you get [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html), in strict mode you get something rational: A `ReferenceError`.)

But separately and more importantly, the timing issue: As of when you're trying to alert it, not only is `publish` undeclared, but even if it were declared it would have no useful value in it, because you haven't set the value yet.

The correct place to alert the value of `publish` would be in the `api` callback where you get the value:

```
FB.api(
   "/me/permissions",
   function (response) {
      var publish;                      // <== declare it
      if(response && !response.error) {
          publish = '1';
      }
      else {
          publish = '0';
      }
      alert(publish);                   // <== use it
   }
);
```

If you need to use `publish` *outside* the `api` callback, you would move the declaration to outside the callback. But you can't **use** `publish` (meaningfully) until that callback has occurred. So for instance:

```
var publish; // <======= Declaration
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
       appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
       xfbml      : true,
       version    : 'v2.1'
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    });

    FB.api(
       "/me/permissions",
       function (response) {
          if(response && !response.error) {
              publish = '1';               // <=== fill it in
          }
          else {
              publish = '0';               // <===
          }
       }
    );
};

function doSomethingWithItLater() {        // <=== A function that uses it
    if (publish) {
        // Do this
    } else {
        // Do that
    }
}

(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

It's important that you don't call `doSomethingWithItLater` until **after** the `api` callback has been called and you've set the value of `publish`. The best way to ensure that is to call it from the callback.

Comment: this code is actually very simplified for the sake of the question. I need to use the variable in the head. It's not a simple alert. This is just for demo

Comment: is there a way to use the variable like you mention but outside the function?

Comment: @MichaelSamuel: This is weird, I didn't get notification of those comments (which the system normally would do automatically). **Why** do you need the variable in the `head` section? What do you need to do with it outside the `api` callback?

Comment: i need to use it in an `if` statement in another function.

Comment: @MichaelSamuel: What other function? Where? To do what? Why in the `head`? Being chary with information is not a great way to get help. :-) I have updated the answer to try to help, but without more to go on, it's really difficult.

Comment: Sorry T.J the code is so complex for the sake of this question. Also I feel it's not safe to expose the whole code here. I now don't need it in the head section. I can use it after the function.I tried it after the function but it lost the value

Comment: @MichaelSamuel: An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is possible at least 99.99% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the variable before the function starts. Then the function will update the variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var publish;
```

Comment: Actually, with the code the OP posted, the variable would get created thanks to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Not likely to be the issue here. (Still best to declare it, though.)